# How can i convert every special character and emoji into its html entity using javascript?

Tags: javascript, encode, emoji

My current code converts characters into entities as expected. But if I convert emoji, then it generates something like �� for  which doesn't render as expected.

```js
String.prototype.toHtmlEntities = function() {
  return this.replace(/./gm, function(s) {
    // return "&#" + s.charCodeAt(0) + ";";
    return (s.match(/[a-z0-9\s]+/i)) ? s : "&#" + s.charCodeAt(0) + ";";
  });
};
console.log("".toHtmlEntities())

document.write("".toHtmlEntities())
```

Answer (score 4):

You're iterating over the *code units* of your string. Instead, you want to iterate over the *code points*. Most emojis consist of one code point, which is encoded by two code units called surrogate pairs - one high and one low one. Surrogate pairs when displayed standalone don't represent a valid symbol, which ends up with `�` being rendered. If you use the [`u` (unicode) flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags) on your regular expression, your `.` will then match based on the code points, allowing you to iterate over each code point (rather than code unit). You can then access the code point value using `codePointAt(0)`, which you can then encode into a HTML entity:

```js
String.prototype.toHtmlEntities = function() {
  return this.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/ugm, s => "&#" + s.codePointAt(0) + ";");
};
console.log("a".toHtmlEntities());
document.write("a".toHtmlEntities());

console.log("&".toHtmlEntities());
document.write("&".toHtmlEntities());

console.log("".toHtmlEntities()); // surrogate pair test
document.write("".toHtmlEntities());

console.log("‍‍‍".toHtmlEntities()); // ZWJ test
document.write("‍‍‍".toHtmlEntities());

console.log("❤️".toHtmlEntities()); // variation selector test
document.write("❤️".toHtmlEntities()); // variation selector test

console.log("ñ".toHtmlEntities()); // decomposed character test (length of 2)
document.write("ñ".toHtmlEntities()); // decomposed character test (length of 2)

console.log("ñ".toHtmlEntities()); // composed character (length of 1)
document.write("ñ".toHtmlEntities()); // composed character (length of 1)
```

If you just want to replace the emoji characters, you can use `/\p{RGI_Emoji}/gv`, or if you can't support that yet as `v` is a new flag, you can use `\p{Emoji_Presentation}` or `\p{Emoji}` to match those (or another regular expression to match your specific characters), and replace those with their code points, eg:

```js
String.prototype.toHtmlEntities = function() {
  return this.replace(/\p{RGI_Emoji}/vgm, s => '&#' +s.codePointAt(0) + ";");
};
console.log("a".toHtmlEntities());
document.write("a".toHtmlEntities());

console.log("&".toHtmlEntities());
document.write("&".toHtmlEntities());

console.log("".toHtmlEntities()); // surrogate pair test
document.write("".toHtmlEntities());

console.log("‍‍‍".toHtmlEntities()); // ZWJ test
document.write("‍‍‍".toHtmlEntities());

console.log("❤️".toHtmlEntities()); // variation selector test
document.write("❤️".toHtmlEntities()); // variation selector test

console.log("ñ".toHtmlEntities()); // decomposed character test (length of 2)
document.write("ñ".toHtmlEntities()); // decomposed character test (length of 2)

console.log("ñ".toHtmlEntities()); // composed character (length of 1)
document.write("ñ".toHtmlEntities()); // composed character (length of 1)
```

As always, if you're going to be modifying the prototype of inbuilt JavaScript objects, ensure you know the [consequences of doing so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice). It is instead recommended to create a new function and pass the string you want to convert into that function as an argument.